# Is it possible to render List Items twice from a single content query web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part

Is it possible to render List Items twice from a single content query web part.

My requirement is something like this:

---

*. Title 1

*. Title 2

*. Title 3

---

*. Title 1
 - Description 1

*. Title 2
 - Description 2

*. Title 3
 - Description 3

---

A common pattern we use while displaying FAQs.

Thanks,

Manoj

Comment: You can create a connected Web Part which shows detail of the List Item, but that will be one at a time!